# Plotting: How to space xticks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

After aggregation, i plotted the numbers but iam struggling to space the xticks

### Aggregation

```
tweet['Retweets']=pd.to_numeric(tweet['Retweets'])
tweet['Favorites']=pd.to_numeric(tweet['Favorites'])
sum_df = tweet.groupby(['Realdate'], as_index=False).agg({'Retweets': 'sum', 'Favorites': 'sum'})
sum_df=sum_df.reset_index()
```

### Plotting

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('Dates')
ax1.set_ylabel('Favorites', color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel('Retweets', color='b')
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
sum_df['Favorites'].plot( kind='bar', color='y', ax=ax1) 
sum_df['Retweets'].plot( kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax2)
ax1.legend(loc=2) # is this the right thing to do to place legends?
ax2.legend(loc=1) # is this the right thing to do to place legends?
ax1.set_xticklabels(sum_df.Realdate.values, rotation=90)
plt.title('Sum of Daily "Likes" and Retweets Time Series')
plt.show()
```

### The resulting output

[image]

Can you please help me with the xticks spacing please? I tried several methods but no results.

Thanks very much

Comment: Well if you set the xticks to every single value on the X axis it'll obviously be too dense to read. What's wrong with the auto-generated xticks?

Comment: Thanks Pranav. I don't mind the auto-generated xticks. How can I set those up with the date limits and the spacing between them ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Tried  `start = pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01')
end = pd.Timestamp('2020-07-14')
x=pd.to_datetime(np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 30))  ax1.set_xticklabels(x.values, rotation=90)`  but the `xticks` get squeezed at the beginning of the x axis they dont get spread evenly

Comment: Does this help? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: Got inspired from your link and I tried `ax1.set_xlim('2020-03-01', '2020-07-15')
ax1.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks()[::10])`  but not working either.